# Load vars based on env in ansible

Tags: ansible, ansible-tower

Team, I have two vars that map to two environments. I want to use them in playbook but only one value should be applied based on env playbook runs on.

ex:

```
var = test1 > should be loaded when env1
var = test2 > should be loaded when env2
```

any hint how can i achieve this in ansible?

I want to write my task in such a way that this variables var carries test1 value when it is run on env1 and vice versa. is there a login I can use at task level? my task is below and when am running my playbook on clusterA it should use var=test1 and when running on clusterB it should use var=test2

```
    - name: Add persistent ddn volume
  mount:
    path: "{{ lustre_client_path }}"
    src: "{{ var }}"
    fstype: lustre
    state: mounted
```

Comment: I suggest you read [Where to set an ansible variable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable) and [How to build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html).

Answer (score -1):

Actually I figured out. I just had to create a separate file and called it configs.yml and place it in each cluster env playbook directly. This worked. So based on env is now loading.